# With block in python file creates local scope?

Tags: python, python-import

I am using the following block of code in a python file names app.py to read JSON data:

```
import json
with open('./mapping/canada_provinces.geojson', 'r') as f:
    countryGeoJSONData = json.load(f)
```

What this block of code seems to do is that the variable countryGeoJsonData variable cannot be imported by any other files within the same directory, such as by using the following import code in another file:

```
from app import countryGeoJSONData
```

Attempting the above, I get an error message that the name countryGeoJSONData could not be imported from app.py.
Why is this happening? Is the with block creating some sort of local context? The variable can be used outside of the with block in the same file. Why can it not be imported into another file?

To help reproduce the situation, here's the contents of app.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Read in Report Data
indicators = pd.read_excel(".\data\In Depth_All Data Export Report.xlsx",3)
contextual = pd.read_excel(".\data\In Depth_All Data Export Report.xlsx",4)

#open the GeoJSON file to show canadian provinces on the map
with open('./mapping/canada_provinces.geojson', 'r') as f:
    countryGeoJSONData = json.load(f)

#unique available indicators 
availableIndicators = indicators["Indicator"].unique()
#unqiue provinces
provinces = indicators[indicators["Reporting level"]=="Province"]["Province/territory"].unique()
```

And then in layout.py, I have the following import code:

```
from app import indicators, contextual, availableIndicators, provinces, countryGeoJSONData
```

which leads to the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'countryGeoJSONData' from 'app'
```

However, if I insert the following code after the with block:

```
importableJSON= countryGeoJSONData
```

then the new variable could be imported into layout.py with no problem. This is why I thought being inside a with block was causing a problem.

```
Project folder structure:
project
-data (includes data files)
-mapping (includes geojson file)
app.py
layout.py
```

Comment: `with` blocks don't create any sort of special scope (they guarantee cleanup of the controlled object, in this case, `f`, but even `f` doesn't have separate scope). Your code as described/written should work, so you haven't provided a [MCVE] for us to work with.

Comment: This should work - is the with statement and assignemnt at module level? If they are inside a function it won't work.

Comment: Personally, I suspect a circular import, but we don't have enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Also, you should not use sole back-slashes for filepaths, even on windows. As the combination of `"\"` + some characters, but not all, will be parsed as special control characters. Aways use `"\\"` or plain forward slashes - `/`

Comment: I have added information to make the situation reproducible

Comment: Sounds like you might have an out-of-date `.pyc` file.

Comment: with the new update, and the assertion it does not break with "file not found", I would say it is a _typo_ in the variable name. If you had extra "import" statements in there, it could be triggering a circular import problem - but it is not the case if the file is there in whole. The `with` statement do not create a local scope. The closer to that is the  ` except` statement error variable - though it is no new scope, it is just deleted at the end of the except block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

The  `with` statement have nothign to do with it - but your  relative filename probably do.

If you tested the module, importing it in the same folder the data folder ("mapping/") is in, it will work. 
It will fail if you try importing this module from any other folder.

The solution for this is to use the module's `__file__` special variable to find the absolute path for your your data file. `pathlib.Path` allows that with minimal fuzz:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path
with (Path(__file__).parent / 'mapping/canada_provinces.geojson').open() as f:
    countryGeoJSONData = json.load(f)
```

(The Path object overrides the "/" separator so Paths can  be compound with strings - that is not a typo)

Comment: That could be a problem, but it would produce a FileNotFoundError or something like that, not the ImportError reported.

Comment: This is very interesting. Your suggestion solves the problem, but I can't understand why it does.
Here's my folder structure:
Project folder
-app.py
-layout.py 
-mapping 
--canada-provinces.geojson
in both cases the json file is being found, but based on your answer, the location of the file and how it is expressed has a bearing on the variable? isn't the variable always in the app.py namespace? I don't understand. Can you help please?

Comment: where is the ".data" folder with the excel files?

Comment: the data folder is also in the project root folder

Comment: I tried to paint a better picture of the project folder structure

Comment: I tried a few variations of filenames. 
Interestingly, what is causing this problem is the use of forward slashes in path name for the GeoJSON file,
If you change the forward slashes to backward slashes, or use your correct way of defining the path, then no problem will happen.

Comment: @EssiShams: I think it's more likely the fact that you changed anything at all, thus updating the file timestamp and preventing the cached `.pyc` from being used.

Comment: hmmmm. I think the variable name was there in the cache as well. It certainly wasn't a new piece of code. the attempt to import was new. Unless I'm missing something. What gave you the clue that .pyc might be out of date? (this is a flask project BTW)

Comment: yes - a mess with the timesamp and an outdated pyc file would clarify all this - just remove all "pyc" files (and `__pycache__` folders).